# .Net Charts - X Axis with Different Intervals

Tags: c#, mschart

I am using .Net Charts. In that, I have displayed a line chart with an Interval of 28 Days.

Here is my code:

```
 Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;
 Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = min;
 Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = max;
 Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 28;
```

But, one of my situation comes like,

28 Days Interval, 35 Days Interval, 28 Days Interval etc. Is that possible to have different Intervals.

Comment: No, Interval is an Axis property and there can only be one.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, `Interval` is an `Axis` property and there can only be **one**.

You can work around this restriction by **drawing** gridlines and labels on your own.

---

Let's assume you have a list of stop points, i.e. the indices of the `DataPoints` where you want a `GridLine` to appear:

```
List<int> stops = new List<int>();
```

After adding a few test numbers `stops.AddRange(new[] { 12, 23, 42, 52, 82 });` we can code the `PostPaint` event of the `Chart` to draw lines:

```
private void chart_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

    ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];

    Font font = ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font;
    Color col = ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor;
    int padding = 10; // pad the labels from the axis

    double aymin = ca.AxisY.Minimum;
    double aymax = ca.AxisY.Maximum;

    int y0 = (int)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(aymin);
    int y1 = (int)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(aymax);

    foreach (int sx  in stops)
    {
        int x = (int)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(chart.Series[0].Points[sx].XValue);

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(col))
            g.DrawLine(pen, x, y0, x, y1);

        string s =  chart.Series[0].Points[sx].XValue + "";
        if (ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format != "") s = string.Format(ax.LabelStyle.Format, s);

        SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(s, font, 999);
        g.DrawString(s, font, Brushes.Black, (int)(x - sz.Width / 2) , y0 + padding);
    }
}
```

After turning off the original `MajorGrid` etc..

```
ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];

ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
ca.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

..this is the result:

[image]

Notes:

- Most of the code are just simple preparations and references. The actual drawing are 2 methods and three or four more lines to get the coordinates..
- I have stored the `DataPoint` **indices** in my List. If you want the custom `GridLines` to be independent of `DataPoints` you can instead store the `Values` and change the List to a `List<double>` andthe two references from  `chart.Series[0].Points[sx].XValue` 
  to accessing the stop values `sx` directly.
- Change the padding value to suit you..
- We can access the axes' minima and maxima values freely, even if they are actually set to `Auto`. This is because we are in a `Paint`event. Otherwise we would have to call `RecalculateAxesScale()` on the `ChartArea`..
- Feel free to make the `Black` label brush dynamic as well..

Comment: Hi TaW, thanks for your response. Instead of using Interval, i have changed the code like this... Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(weekEndDate, DT1.Rows[i]["VALUE"].ToString());''. So that, eventhough there are differences in interval, it getting binded without any issues.