# How to put a logarithmic scale with rows represented in logarithm on chart in C #

Tags: c#, charts, logarithm

I'm developing a chart in C # and I need the graph lines to be represented in logarithm, the scale can already put, just missing the vertical lines in logarithmic scale according to the image below:

[image]

My chart currently looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Correcting ... I would like to know how to put the line breaks in logarithm

Comment: I doubt chart will do that for you. There is no natural spacing for this. You will have to define the interval rules for yourself. - See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244461/display-tick-labels-in-logarithmic-scale-ms-chart-log-log/37274421?s=2|1.7051#37274421) for an example of placing customlabels on a logarithmic axis. You will have to adapt it to owner-draw your majorgridlines in the pre/postpaint event. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093988/net-charts-x-axis-with-different-intervals/43115676?s=1|0.0000#43115676) for an exmaple of drawing gridlines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

To get those additional lines between the periods you need to turn on the MinorGrid for the x-axis of your chartArea:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
```

This is obviosly a lot easier than drawing them yourself, as I thought was necessary..

I leave the owner-drawn solution below, though, as it may be useful when doing extra special stuff, like using unsusual pens or customizing the intervals..

(And I was glad to see that the results are identical :-)

[image]

**Old solution with owner-drawn GridLines:**

Here is how you can **owner-draw** the gridlines for a logarithmic axis.

To define the **interval rules** I first collect a List of double values for the stop values. along the x-axis.

Here is an example using 10 gridlines in each period..

The chart's x-axis was set up with `Minimum = 0.1d` and `Maximum = 1000`.

[image]

```
private void chart_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
    Graphics g = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    // first get y top and bottom values:
    int y0 = (int)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(ca.AxisY.Minimum);
    int y1 = (int)ca.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(ca.AxisY.Maximum);

    int iCount = 10;                         // number of gridlines per period
    var xes = new List<double>();            // the grid position values
    double xx = ca.AxisX.Minimum;
    do {
       xx *= ca.AxisX.LogarithmBase;         // next period
       double delta = 1d * xx / iCount ;     // distance in this period
       for (int i = 1; i < icount; i++) xes.Add(i * delta);  // collect the values
    }  while (xx < ca.AxisX.Maximum);

    // now we can draw..
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(64, Color.Blue))
          {DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot} )
       foreach (var xv in xes)
       {
           float x = (float)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(xv);
           g.DrawLine(pen, x, y0, x, y1);
       }
}
```

You could cache the x-values list but would have to re-calculate whenever the data or the axis view changes..

Note that, when collection the grid stop values, we count from 1 because we don't want to double the starting points of a period: `1..9 + 10..90` etc. So we actually add only `count-1` grid stops..