# Display specific Major ticks c# chart

Tags: c#, charts, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to display a specific array of numbers as major ticks in c# chart. Any ideas?
For example, I want [0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2] ticks to be displayed on the x axis and [0.00005, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05] on y axis. Note that my axis are logarithmic scaled.
Anyone knows how to customize the axis to show these arrays ticks? In other terms, my question is how to display the tickmarks for the mentioned values only without having any other tickmarks? see the following image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAnhS.png) to understand what I mean. I was able the customize the labels but not the tickmarks.

Thanks in advance,

Mohamad.

Comment: To clarify, the question is how to show the ticks of these values only ? I have added the labels and the ticks but I am having additional minor ticks.

Comment: All ticks and gridlines automatically  are evenly spaced. For any other spacing you will need to draw them yourself.

Comment: If you just want to enable the minor ticks simply write: `yourAxis.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;`

Comment: @TaW I have both major and minor tickmark enabled, my question is how to display the ticks for the mentioned values only without having any other ticks. do you have any idea on how to make that?

Comment: As I wrote: This is not possible. You need to draw to custom ticks yourself. For this you need to understand the basics of drawing and also the 3 coordinate systems in MSChart. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+coordinate+systems) are a few post about this. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667315/how-to-put-a-logarithmic-scale-with-rows-represented-in-logarithm-on-chart-in-c/43668927#43668927) is about drawing logarithmic custom gridlines..

Answer (score 0):

you can use ZedGraph. it show logarithmic diagrams and you can set x-axis and y-axis easily